Horror/thriller movie with a woman that is being stalked by a man from a carnival or circus
A number of years ago I watched a film and I only remember one scene. It was near the end of the film. 
A woman was being stalked by a man from a carnival or circus. The man painted himself the same pattern or colour as the woman's wallpaper at home and hid by standing still against the wall. The woman arrived home an was unaware of the stranger in her home until he stepped out in front of her. 
This was a very memorable scene and I would like to know the name of the film. I think the film included other carnival or circus related horror.
I believe I watched this movie on TV in the late 90s in the UK. I think the female lead was a well known actress in her mid 20s. 

Welcome, please see if you can edit your question with the following details, year you saw, when is the movie likely from, did you see it in theaters or was it made for tv, country, language, the man and the woman, how did they look like and any other plot details you remember.

The movie is When a Stranger Calls (1979), or When a Stranger Rings (UK) and remade in 2006.

In the beginning a woman is babysitting and experiences a situation where someone keeps calling and threatening her. Eventually she realizes that the call is coming from within the house. She escapes but the children are murdered. Years later the woman is severely traumatized and encounters the same threats yet again. In the last scene the perpetrator has camouflaged himself against her brick wall inside her house.


Yes the brick wall I remember now, many thanks.

I found the actual film I was looking for. The film was called 'When a Stranger Calls Back'. Another remake of the original When a Stranger Calls.

The actual film in question was When a Stranger Calls Back (1993).
